# Is there a name for a portrait without a person, like a desk where someone was working, or a bed?

Tags: portrait, terminology

I planned to take pictures of people for a school assignment but quickly realized I didn't have many models to take pictures of and decided I would take portraits without people but as a photo it would need a subject/photo type and description which I can find a name for it. A few words I saw for this type of photography were "candid" and "portrait-less".

Comment: Without a person, I wouldn't consider a photo a portrait.  But would need more info about the subject to classify.  Could be architecture, real estate, landscape, urban landscape, street, etc.  If there is no real subject, it could be considered a "snapshot".

Comment: Not sure about that... A photograph of (for example) Einstein's office desk/notes/blackboard as he left them would certainly give you information about the man. One definition of 'portrait' is "a representation or impression of someone or something in language or on film.
"the writer builds up a full and fascinating portrait of a community"

Comment: @BobT That is a metaphorical portrait, not a literal one.  To build that type of "portrait" would involve multiple photos that could individually be classified within other genres.  A single non-portrait photo wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: It seems "metaphorical portrait" is already taken ;( Pity, the term would be perfect.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's an established term for this, but van Gogh once [wrote his brother Theo](http://www.webexhibits.org/vangogh/letter/20/626a.htm) (translation by Mrs. Johanna van Gogh-Bonger) about a painting he did to show Gaugin's absence:

> ... A few days before we parted company, when my illness forced me to go into an asylum, I tried to paint “his empty place.”
>
> [It is a study of his wooden armchair, brown and dark red, the seat of
> greenish straw, and in place of the absent person, a lighted candle in a candlestick and some modern novels.](http://www.webexhibits.org/vangogh/data/images/Vincent/Arles/F0499.jpg) Should the opportunity arise, do please take another look at this study by way of a reminder of him. It is done throughout in broken tones of green and red. ...

So, I'd go with "empty place" photography.

Answer (score 4):

It's only a portrait if there's a person in it, strictly.

Photographs of objects could be categorised as **[still life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_life)** or [still life photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photography#Types).
Though traditionally these were paintings or photographs of fruit or stuffed animals arranged on a table, the concept could be extended to include desktop detritus, paperwork, or equipment, arranged to make an interesting composition.

If there is no clearly discernible single object or grouping as the subject of the photo, then it could perhaps be considered Real Estate or even Photojournalism; perhaps depending on whether it attempts to 'show off the room' or 'tell a story'.

Answer (score 3):

You could call it an "impression on a room", like the impression left on a bed.  Or a "portrait minus one".  Or an "environmental portrait".  Or "signature spaces".  Or just "habitats".  Essentially there is no really established standing expression so you get to pick your own and hope that the teacher will run along with it.